# Build a binary tree using two arrays given in C

Tags: c, arrays, tree, binary-tree

I have a question. How can I add two arrays L(elements of theleft subtree) and D(elements of the right subtree) and create a binary tree? It's not a binary search tree. However these data that i have are stored in a file in which i have managed to convert the lines with numbers into int arrays S->Left elements and D->Right elements. Finally with the p i have stored the number of nodes from the first line. The file contains these lines:

> 7   ->Number of nodes
>
> 2 4 0 0 7 0 0 ->Left subtree elements
>
> 3 5 6 0 0 0 0 ->Right subtree elements

However my assignment is to build this code and do a postorder,inorder and preorder traversal of the binary tree and the output should look like this:

> Preorder: 1 2 4 5 7 3 6
>
> Inorder: 4 2 7 5 1 3 6
>
> Postorder: 4 7 5 2 6 3 1

It's not clear for me why 1 is there. I am sure that 1 is the root but i don't know how to add the rest of the elements to the binary tree from S and D arrays.

My code so far looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  int p;
  int length1, length2,  *S,  *D;
  int j = 0, k;
  const char *v1;
  const char *v2;

  FILE *fptr = fopen("sd.in", "r");
  if (fptr == NULL)
  {
    printf("Failed to open file\n");
    return  - 1;
  }
  char buf[3][100];
  int i = 0;

  while ((fgets(buf[i], 100, fptr) != NULL) && (i < 3))
  {
    printf("%s\n", buf[i++]);
  }

  fclose(fptr);

  p = atoi(buf[0]);
  v1 = buf[1];
  v2 = buf[2];
  length1 = strlen(v1);
  length2 = strlen(v2);
  S = (int*)malloc(length1 *sizeof(int));
  D = (int*)malloc(length2 *sizeof(int));

  while (sscanf(v1, "%d%n", &S, &length1) == 1)
  {
    printf(" element %d is %d\n", j, S);
    v1 += length1;
    j++;
  }

  while (sscanf(v2, "%d%n", &D, &length2) == 1)
  {
    printf(" element %d is %d\n", k, D);
    v2 += length2;
    k++;
  }

  printf("%d\n", p);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code is unreadable. Please indent it according to some C guidelines.

Comment: What do you mean by that? The code works for me.

Comment: You have inconsistent, and nonexistent spacing.

Comment: Ok i will edit it.

Comment: I didn't say it won't compile, I said it's unreadable. There are indentation standards and guidelines. Look at some C code examples to get the general idea.

Comment: I have edited it now. I hope it is better.

Comment: Nope.. That's not good indentation.. You'll have to look at some examles.. here's a random page with C code in it.. http://beginnersbook.com/2014/01/c-functions-examples/

Comment: I am sorry sir,but can you show me what specific lines or segments are unreadable? I really think that everything is in order with the reading,i can explain some segments if you want and you don't understand.

Comment: When you scan and print the array elements, you must use `S[j]` and `D[k]` instead of just `S` and `D`. Turning on warnings will tell you about type mismatches with the variadic library functions. You should also initialise `k` to 0 and free the allocated memory after use.

Comment: As you can see over there when i am printing {printf(" element %d is %d\n",k,D); i think what you just said is just a matter of writing? am I right or wrong?